# ScrollPance moving with node Javafx

Tags: javafx, scrollpane

I have a scroll Pane with a rectangle inside the scroll Pane.The rectangle can only move left or right . The scroll pane has a with of 800,when the windows gets to small the scrollbar becomes enabled and you can scroll. My problem is when i try to move the rectangle when the scrollbar is on , the scroll bar will also move either left or right.Is the a way to temporary disable the scroll feature when i am moving the node >

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you might be looking for is

```
public final void setPannable(boolean value)
```

> Sets the value of the property pannable.
>   Property description:
>   Specifies whether the user should be able to pan the viewport by using the mouse. If mouse events reach the ScrollPane (that is, if mouse events are not blocked by the contained node or one of its children) then pannable is consulted to determine if the events should be used for panning.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ScrollPane.html#setPannable-boolean-

I'm not sure if this works, but sounds like it.

You also could use https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#onMouseClickedProperty

or a similar MouseProperty, set up a Listener and make it so that when you click on the ScrollPane, it will set https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy.html

to NEVER

```
public static final ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy NEVER
```

> Indicates that a scroll bar should never be shown.

then back to your original setting for `ScrollPane.onMouseReleased();`

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you . The scrollPane was set to pannable

Comment: Great, I'm glad it worked out for you!  It's most likely true by default.